# Can I use size classes in xib file in IOS 8.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios-universal-app

My app is a universal app, i.e. the app is for iPhone_portrait and iPad_landscape.

I searched a lot about how to deal with iPhone and iPad, and I found that I can make my add adaptive using size classes, especially after IOS 8 [size classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26368117/4498576)

**my question is :**

1. Is this solution is a the best one, even if the design wan't simple?
2. I have a lot of xib files in my app. Can I use size classes in this case? Or I need two xib one for iPhone, one for iPad?

thanks.

Comment: Size classes where create so you do not need two different files for iPhone to iPad. And yes you just change the NIB file to use the size classes, just enable size classes on the first tab for the nib property inspector.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use size class and AutoLayout. see the following screen shot there is tick mark on right side in File inspector.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer. 
but does that work even if the xib was for tableview cell, collectionView cell, .. 
because when i create it, there is a choice if i want it for iPad, or iPhone.

Comment: you need to use auto-layout as well only size class in not enough

Comment: what did you mean by auto-layout?

Comment: Check what is autolayout https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html that manage  subview's parent view